# How do I get input files to be FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

So I have this form, that allows users to upload audio file and an image file at the same time.

However when I am testing this code, I am noticing the alert is only giving me basic data back and has not included the form data.

```
function PodcastUpload({ data }) {
  
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("podcastupload"));
    
   var json =  JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()));

    alert(json);
    console.log('You clicked submit.');
  }


    return (<>
        <h1>Upload New Episode</h1>
        <h2>{data}</h2>
        <form id="podcastupload" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >

          <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple></input>
          <input name="uuid" value="62569301efd5e89879d13b29"/>
          <input name="show_id" value="617414548b226e7231bfba5b"/>
          <input name="show_b" value="proptech"/>
          <input name="season" value="4"/>
          <input name="episode_no" value="40"/>
          <input name="title" value="test title"/>
          <textarea name="description"></textarea>
          <input name="explicit" value="false"/>
          <input type="date" name="pubDate"/>
          
          <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </>)

}
```

The alert returns:

```
{"file":{},"uuid":"62569301efd5e89879d13b29","show_id":"617414548b226e7231bfba5b","show_b":"proptech","season":"4","episode_no":"40","title":"test title","description":"","explicit":"false","pubDate":"2022-09-08"}
```

Which means somewhere it has lost the file info.

I am wondering how can I make sure that am able to submit the file data with an Ajax request.

I first developed the backend using Postman and there code generator says I need too do something like this. But clearly that is not using a HTML form for the end user.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'http://localhost:3000/api/podcasts/gupload',
  'headers': {
    'Cookie': 'next-auth.session-token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..OWf8yhLsBihBAl3N.EMeo_KcosE6QlogUi22Kps6z3lyeyQlk3vP9lNdyvlqDaA8SKOXJtpv3cfrAIVMn7CaBcLDKysAIy3KAFYWCYyFg3hpzwh6yNkTTn65Y_ktuH-N0u_sUCQ1i_dhhVTUHK-q3ck6ttzPIsfD_9YogHWj4ha2GaO72ukMval_7P8CN9OVt0ZBmBCbjyQY-UoZCeFi9qRRac994ReHy_oRUPeF3Cbv-4Nrm9G3MtK1A2X25YIRlDowiehQwFUU_8Kb1fcaEzFE.rm3d-QIASavADhiMmBqqzQ'
  },
  formData: {
    'file': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream('/Users/russellharrower/Downloads/S04E02.png'),
      'options': {
        'filename': 'S04E02.png',
        'contentType': null
      }
    },
    'file': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream('/Users/russellharrower/Desktop/S04E02.mp3'),
      'options': {
        'filename': 'S04E02.mp3',
        'contentType': null
      }
    },
    'uuid': '62569301efd5e89879d13b29',
    'show_id': '617414548b226e7231bfba5b',
    'show_b': 'Test',
    'season': '4',
    'episode_no': '2',
    'title': 'Test',
    'description': '<pTest</p>',
    'explicit': 'false',
    'pubDate': '2022-09-25T14:00:00+08:00'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const file = document.getElementById("file")
formData.append("file",file)
```

you can add something like this. let me know if it works otherwise we can check for something else.